# Angular calculated incorrect element height

Tags: angular

I am using this code in component.html to hide child elements elements on click:

```
<grandparentcomponent <--wraps everything, the height I need-->
      //more divs
      <div class="dropIcon align-middle fa" (click)="toggleEffects()"></div>
      <div class="dropdown" [hidden]="effectsHidden">
         //more divs
      </div>
</grandparentcomponent>
```

In component.ts I am inejcting a directive appPanelHeight and emitting the height of a grandparent component inside of toggleEffects() function:

```
  toggleEffects() {
    this.effectsHidden = !this.effectsHidden;
    this.heightService.height.next(this.appPanelHeight.height);
  }
```

Custom directive code:

```
export class PanelHeightDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {    
   }
     get height() {
     return this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
   }

}
```

The problem is that the height I emit is not the current one, but the one 
before `effectsHidden` changed. To further explain the issue.. if I wrap the Subject.next() call into a setTimeout, I indeed get the correct height:

```
  toggleEffects() {
    this.effectsHidden = !this.effectsHidden;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.heightService.height.next(this.appPanelHeight.height);
    }, 1);

  }
```

The same issue happens if I use jQuery to get the grand parent component height. What is going on here? Why do I need to use setTimeout? I feel like this is bad practice and it will lead to further issues down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly invoke change detection before reading the height, to ensure Angular has updated the view bindings:

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

toggleEffects() {
  this.effectsHidden = !this.effectsHidden;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  this.heightService.height.next(this.appPanelHeight.height);
}
```

Comment: aaa, dankeschön :) This is the first time I even hear of ChangeDetectorRef.  May I ask what source did you use to learn so much Angular?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular ;-) ,https://github.com/angular/angular and github.com/angular/angular/issues